# Jquery animation faking the async

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I googled and confirmed that there is no async thing in animate(), but couldn't find any solution for my case.

Demo http://www.bootply.com/mTPm9tr8Iu

in my demo, when you hover over first box u will see the 4th (bottom right) change it's css to margin-top:-100px and vice versa for the right first box. As you can see it seem not so smooth, how to fix that?

Comment: try to use animate function in jquery, that will behave like animation.. and that will be smooth... or use slideDown () .. this will also behave smooth..

Comment: you could also use css3 animation. see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: sorry I meant css3 transition http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: @Guillaume added transition but look even worse http://www.bootply.com/gyEJYEzFei

Comment: @DeDevelopers but how can u ensure it will trigger the same time with the earlier animate function?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what the final result should be.

The way you constructed your dom tree makes it very difficult to achieve. It would be easier if you had columns instead of cells. That way you dont have to bother about the forth cell positioning.

see how I did it : http://www.bootply.com/g2i7xGm0fb

I hope that it will be what you expected.

note: There is no use of jquery in this solution.